# Why are the mother and sister of Darnell/Harry Monroe present at his wedding?

Tags: my-name-is-earl

Due to a past of having done done shady things for the government Harry Monroe lives under the new identity Darnell in Camden. It seems that Camden was just a randomly picked location to continue his life in. However in the episode where he and Joy marry, his sister and mother are also present. They both appear to live nearby. I also vaguely remember that another episode featured an aunt of Darnell in Camden or nearby. Is this discrepancy of him living under a new identity in a random place while at the same time interacting with family living nearby explained somewhere in the series?